# Load-time weaving stopped working after upgrading to Spring-5

Tags: java, spring

I use:

```
<context:spring-configured />
<context:load-time-weaver/>
```

I have -javaagent:/path/to/spring-instrument-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar

Using Spring-4.x this worked fine but after upgrading to Spring-5 no aop.xml files are picked up.
Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: did you include spring-aop?

Comment: Yes, none of the "core-deps" changed
(don't know how to format code here on SO, too lazy to find out before replying...)

  <version.spring>5.1.3.RELEASE</version.spring>

   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>${version.spring}</version>
   </dependency>

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck with the same issue and the solution for me was to 
use this construction:

```
<context:load-time-weaver aspectj-weaving="on" />
```

So, when I set **aspectj-weaving="on"** directly, it solves the issue.